# More background colors without gradients?

Tags: css

Is there any css function like linear-gradient which renders provided colors without gradient?
Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I can see from your answer I did not described the problem right. What I need is split some div into 2 background areas when each is filled with given color but there is no gradient. Just 2 colors with sharp color edge in between. That is why I mentioned linear-gradient function. I would be happy with the function of same signature but without providing this gradient feature.

Comment: I have updated my answer but still i used `gradient`, is there any reson in specific that you don't want to use gradient?

Comment: @A.J Thank you, the reason I did not want to use a gradient was I thought it had had another meaning of parameters. Now I know how to use it and linear-gradient is exactly what I need. Sorry, I should have red the documentation first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**With gradients** you achieve it. Try this:

```
background: -webkit-repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(255,255,255,0), rgba(255,255,255,0) 80px, rgba(255,255,255,0.2) 80px, rgba(255,255,255,0.2) 150px);
background: -moz-repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(255,255,255,0), rgba(255,255,255,0) 80px, rgba(255,255,255,0.2) 80px, rgba(255,255,255,0.2) 150px);
background: -o-repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(255,255,255,0), rgba(255,255,255,0) 80px, rgba(255,255,255,0.2) 80px, rgba(255,255,255,0.2) 150px);
background: -ms-repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(255,255,255,0), rgba(255,255,255,0) 80px, rgba(255,255,255,0.2) 80px, rgba(255,255,255,0.2) 150px);
background: repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(255,255,255,0), rgba(255,255,255,0) 80px, rgba(255,255,255,0.2) 80px, rgba(255,255,255,0.2) 150px);
background-color: green;
box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
```

Check this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/1n40RqTftrPaOIJmoFBY?p=info)

(Source : http://www.the-art-of-web.com/css/linear-gradients/)

Update as per ur comment:

Check this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/1n40RqTftrPaOIJmoFBY?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

You can create all sorts of patterns, including stripes, arrows, zig-zags, etc.

Example for zig-zag-patterns:

```
background: 
linear-gradient(135deg, #ECEDDC 25%, transparent 25%) -50px 0,
linear-gradient(225deg, #ECEDDC 25%, transparent 25%) -50px 0,
linear-gradient(315deg, #ECEDDC 25%, transparent 25%),
linear-gradient(45deg, #ECEDDC 25%, transparent 25%);   
background-size: 100px 100px;
background-color: #EC173A;
```

(Source: http://lea.verou.me/css3patterns/ )